# Getting correct index row from sectioned tableview after JSON download Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

JSON data is already alphabetized before being downloaded. The app correctly divides the data into sections, creates the section title based off of the first letter, and lists all names starting with that letter in the correct section. The problem is each section repeats the same data once it transitions to the detail view controller. Sections B, C, etc. show all of correct names but repeat the "A" names when going to the detail view controller. How can I get the selected cell and the details view controller to match again?

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return figuresByLetter.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return figuresByLetter[section].key
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return figuresByLetter[section].value.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "figureCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = figuresByLetter[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)
} 

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? FigureViewController {
        destination.figure = figures[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
    }
}
```

Let me know if there is any other code needed to answer the question!

```
struct FigureStats: Decodable {
let name: String
let number: String
let weapon: String?
let desc: String?
let year: String?
}
```

In the detail view controller:

```
class FigureViewController: UIViewController {
var figure:FigureStats?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    nameLabel.text = figure?.name
    numberLabel.text = figure?.number
    weaponLabel.text = figure?.weapon
    descLabel.text = figure?.desc
    yearLabel.text = figure?.year
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this property. I hope it helps you.

```
class YourClass: UIViewController {

var currentFigure: FigureStats!

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return figuresByLetter.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return figuresByLetter[section].key
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return figuresByLetter[section].value.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "figureCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = figuresByLetter[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
currentFigure = figuresByLetter[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.row]
print(currentFigure)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)
} 

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? FigureViewController {
        print(currentFigure)
        destination.figure = currentFigure
    }
}

class FigureViewController: UIViewController {
var figure:FigureStats?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(figure)
    nameLabel.text = figure?.name
    numberLabel.text = figure?.number
    weaponLabel.text = figure?.weapon
    descLabel.text = figure?.desc
    yearLabel.text = figure?.year
    }
}
```

Comment: Error: "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'FigureStats' with no arguments"
Did you change the FigureStats struct?

Comment: @MedicineMan Try change "var currentFigure = FigureStats" to "var currentFigure: FigureStats"

Comment: now error: "Class 'ViewController' has no initializers

Comment: @MedicineMan Try change "var currentFigure: FigureStats" to "var currentFigure: FigureStats!"

Comment: I already tried that myself. Detail view controller now shows the wrong data. It is always the same wrong data as well.

Comment: @MedicineMan I change the code for the answer, please add print and tell me what you see.

Comment: First print shows all figures. Second print shows last figure data and not the one I clicked on. Third print shows same as second.

Comment: @MedicineMan It's my mistake, sorry. I change the code again, I hope it's working good.

Comment: @MedicineMan Can you write to me, if it works for you? Thanks.

Comment: You my friend are a genius! Thank you so much. It finally works as it is supposed to!

Comment: @MedicineMan hooray, we did it) I very glad that we did it.

Comment: Me too! I appreciate all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you don't send data to your showDetails (I don't see how you do it) so you see data which did add to storyboard but not data from your model, check it.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: indexPath)
} 

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetails" {
        let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! YourViewController
        let row = (sender as! IndexPath).row

        controller.figuresByLetter = figuresByLetter[row]
    }
}
```

Comment: @MedicineMan You should change YourViewController to your viewcontroller and create a property for detail controller  (for example figuresByLetter) and get data from your property and insert in your outlets.
If you have some questions do not hesitate to ask me and I'd be happy to help. If you do not have a question, close this question, please.

Comment: The detail view controller gets all of its inputs from a struct. var figure:FigureStats? and FigureStats is the struct that contains name and description.

Comment: @MedicineMan Can you send screens because I don't understand (I know the English language very little)

Comment: @MedicineMan Can you make a breakpoint for testing the value that contains in the object? If you can't it's no big deal. We can be using print for 3 place: 1. after "cell.textLabel?.text = figuresByLetter[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.row].name". 2. before "destination.figure = figures[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]" 3. before "nameLabel.text = figure?.name"
Can do you tell me, which data you see?

Comment: 1. after "cell.textLabel?.text = figuresByLetter[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.row].name" shows all correct names.

Comment: 2. before "destination.figure = figures[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]" shows the repeated names in each section. The problem is here.

Comment: @MedicineMan try to using this code 
"let row = (sender as! IndexPath).row
 let row = (sender as! IndexPath).row
 controller.figuresByLetter = figuresByLetter[indexPath.section].value[row]"
 instead of 
"destination.figure = figures[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]"

Comment: @MedicineMan you also should remove this line "performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)" and add this line "performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: indexPath)"

Comment: I already did that. It still has the error. I do not have a navigation controller though. I am using a tab bar controller. Does that change things?

Comment: @MedicineMan can you send your project for me? I need show code, it'S way the fastest to help you.

Comment: Send me a personal message in chat.

Comment: @MedicineMan I don't know how to send personal message, sorry.

Comment: @MedicineMan Can you add to archive your project?

Comment: I do not know how.

Comment: @MedicineMan http://imagehost7.online-image-editor.com/oie_upload/images/OIE_2015_18215989_99444821/212256399TYGaF0Z.png

Comment: This is all I can figure out to do. I'm sorry.